# How to remove the empty values of an array without removing the keys and also without resetting the keys

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to remove the empty values of an array without removing the keys and also without resetting the keys.

```
 Eg:
    [0]= "test1"
    [1]= ""
    [2]= "test2"
```

Doing array_filter results in the following output:

```
    [0]= "test1"
    [2]= "test2"
```

Here the key is also removed. Is there a way to remove only the values without removing the keys to get an output like :

```
    [0]= "test1"
    [1]= "test2"
```

Is there any php function that does it?

Comment: Your desired output does not match your question: You *do* want to reset the keys as your second element has a different key.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array_values` to get all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically.

```
$arr = array("test1","","test2");

$result = array_values( array_filter( $arr ) );

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test1
    [1] => test2
)
```

Comment: For example if my array key is   array:3 [▼
  1 => "test1"
  3 => "test2"
  5 => "test3"
], then array_values( array_filter( $arr ) ) will reset the array as   array:3 [▼
  0 => "test1"
  1 => "test2"
  2 => "test3"
]

Comment: @Programmer yes that should be the outpuy

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_filter function for it

```
    $arr = ['test1','','test2'];
     echo '<pre />';
     print_r(array_filter($arr));
```

it will show you the following result

```
 Array
(
    [0] => test1
    [2] => test2
)
```